# kendo ui grid datasource how to update filters to send all filter values

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, datasource

I have a grid with filter header in every columns. When the user type something in a filter, the datasource send a request to the server to get the data. This is fine when is only one column filter. The problem is when the user after obtain the filtered results needs to filter by another column, and without to remove the previous filter type something in other column filter. In this second situation i need to send all filter values and not only the second filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what language you use. I assume you do it with javascript.
So you can use the code below.

```
 var grid = $('#ClientsGrid').data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.filter({
                    field: "client_status",
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: "2"
```

If you need to clear all filters, you can use

```
var grid =('#ClientsGrid').data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.filter({});
```

Comment: Thanks @Burak. quick cuestion, Can I do that before the grid start the request to the server? If the answer is Yes please What is the correct event that i need to handle.

Comment: Hi @nes15411, you can check this page to choose the right example for you https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

Comment: Thanks @Burak  I'll check your link.